# PHP not connecting with server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, host

I have the following PHP code:

**(db/connect.php)**
[image]

**(index.php)**
[image]

And I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I have a Linux CPanel and an external webhost: GoDaddy

Why can I not connect?

Thanks :)

Is this the db_user:

[image]

Comment: What is the root of index.php..? is it in db directory of outside the db directory?

Comment: Your title is incorrect. you are using db/Connect.php) with a capital "C" but the screenshot shows your php file with lowercase "c" (connect.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Connect to Godaddy**
Your mysqli connection lists "localhost" as the first parameter. You are trying to connect to a database locally. You need to connect to a host remotely, through Godaddy. You will need to lookup the connection information through your CPanel.
You will need to create and/or locate the following MySql database information:
 1. hostname
 2. username
 3. db_password
 4. db_name

**Using Class mysqli**
You are using: `$db = new mysql`. You need to use `$db = new mysqli_connect`
`mysqli_connect` needs four paramerters:

```
mysqli_connect("host_name","db_user","password","db_name");
```

The code in your db/Connect.php should look like this:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("host_name","db_user","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I have edited the question above - is this what the user should be: User: cpses_rhoeIBPMZK@localhost

Comment: No, you only need to enter the user name. Here is a link to Go Daddy that might help. https://www.godaddy.com/help/connecting-to-mysql-using-php-216

Answer (score 1):

the directory should be as following

```
htdocs
|---test-db
|    |---index.php
|    |---db
|         |---connect.php
|
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - this is the directory that i am using - and for some reason it is still not working

Comment: you should check the file name.. it is connect.php, not Connect.php.. It is a good programming practice that not using capital letters for first letter of the file.. use camelCase..

Answer (score 0):

Your connection link should be

```
require 'db/Connect.php';
```

That is `Connect.php` starts with uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was just wondering why the capitalisation matters in this instance?

Comment: *nix (Linux, Unix & MacOS) all use filesystems that are case sensitive which means that Connect.php and connect.php are two different files.